# strange record order of Realm

Tags: ios, realm, sequences

I'm using realm db(https://realm.io/) in iOS app, I found a strange behavior. I insert several records to a table in the order record1, record2 and record3, however, in one of my customer's iPad, the order of read result is random, but in my iPad, the read order is always the same as insert:record1, record2 and record3.

Does anyone has some clues why that happen?

Comment: there is no delete, edit after insert.

Comment: it's always random fetching, you should sort after fetch or add timestamp on object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the ordering of Realm objects when inserted into a database isn't guaranteed.

If you want to explicitly control the ordering of a list of objects, best practice is to create another Realm model class (eg `MyObjectList`), add a Realm `List` object to it, and add the objects you wish to order as children of that object.

Another way is to add an extra property to your objects, like `orderedIndex` and have that incrementing upwards. When you query for your objects, you then use the `.sort()` method to sort by that property.

Comment: What if I have like 10k objects in a realm and want to sort them by an orderedIndex property? Is there any lazy-loading trick when it comes to sorting or we anyways will face a performance degrade when sorting a huge amount of data? @TiM